# Gradient Texture changes when posing armature

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, armature

I've created a radial gradient texture I'm pretty happy with, and I've connected it to an armature I wish to animate. The material reads perfectly in the default pose state, but once I start to move it, the radial gradient starts sliding all over the geometry. I'd like this material to remain the same, no matter what direction it's posed in. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Material node is attached below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are using the _Object_ coordinates for the _Gradient Texture_, they go from negative to positive along the object's local axes, with 0 at the origin point. Deforming the petals with an armature does not change the object's orientation according to the deformation. To keep the gradient attached to the posed mesh you have to use a UV map with the petals UV unwrapped. Or _Generated_ like suggested by @moonboots can work too, depends a lot on the deformation.

Comment: You're right, UV will be simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem with the *Object* output when you rig the object, the texture won't follow, instead use the *Generated* output (it will need some adjustments of the *Mapping* node though), or the *UV* output as Gordon suggests (in that case make sure that the unwrapping is good).

Comment: Just edited my comment because your solution can work as well ;)